# Prepended Image not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, manifest.json

I've been working on a small Chrome Extension to put together the things I've been learning. It's intended to remove the suggested reel on youtube and replace it with a motivational image to stay focused while studying. So far it works as intended but the image won't show, I've rewriting the 4th line in many different ways and can't seem to figure out what I should do different or if the issue is elsewhere. If anyone needs me to upload the code for may manifest.json folder let me know.

Thanks in Advance!

```
const contents = $("#contents");
const contentsParent = contents.parent();
contents.remove();
contentsParent.prepend("<img src='./images/motivated.jpg'>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution to the issue I was having and thought I'd post it in case someone sees this in the future. It looks like there was an issue with contents not being assigned it's value before the rest of the code ran so I worked around it with a setInterval that checks to see if contents has a value. Also created a URL version of the image I had saved since it was not uploaded before and this worked. Lastly I also added web accessible resources to my manifest.json file as you will see below.

```
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "resources": ["images/motivated.png"]
    }]
```

````
function main(){
const contents = $("#contents");
if(!contents[0]) return;

window.clearInterval(checkId);

const contentsParent = contents.parent();
contents.remove();

// contentsParent.prepend("<img src='images/motivated.png'>");
const imgURL = chrome.runtime.getURL("images/motivated.png");
const htmlString = `<img class= "image" src="${imgURL}">`;
contentsParent.prepend(htmlString)
contentsParent.prepend("<h1>Get back to studying!</h1>").addClass("words")
}   ```
````